# Displaying Bottom Border of a Table - Erratic in Chrome

Tags: html, html-table

I am having a problem with a table bottom border occasionally not showing in Chrome. At least, I think it's only Chrome: being an erratic problem, it's a bit hard to be sure.

The tables in question are the "Little Hotels Featured Hotel", "Review of the Week", "Subscribe to Our Newsletter" and "Find Us on Facebook" boxes at the bottom of http://www.littlehotelsofspain.co.uk.

The code is:

```
<table width="364" border="1" bordercolor="#999999" style="border-collapse:collapse">
<tr>
<td height="32" bgcolor="#EDEFF4" style="padding-left:10px">
<font face="Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif" color="#333"><strong>Little Hotels Featured Hotel</strong></font>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="padding-left:10px">
<br>
<?php dadedadeda ?>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Typically when I open the page, one or two of the bottom borders are not showing. Moving the scroll slider up and down so the problem area disappears and reappears sometimes corrects or changes it.

Comment: Chrome 19 on Mac, reloaded several times, I don't see any missing borders.

Comment: IE9 and latest FF and Chrome looking the same here... Can also not see any missing border =/

Comment: Thanks to @lanzz for taking the trouble to look. I wonder if it's something unique to my computer then. I just looked again and found that when I open the page, all the tables are below the fold. When I scroll down, one or more may then be missing the bottom border. If I scroll back up, release the mouse, then down again, the borders will be different (sometimes they have all come back). If I refresh the page while the tables are visible, all the borders appear. Odd!

Comment: It seems that Chrome sometimes has a problem rendering a 1 pixel line. i tried increasing the border to 2 pixels and the problem went away. Now the problem is that 2 pixels looks ugly so I have to stick with 1 pixel. I've hated IE for years and always praised Firefox, an more recently Chrome. It seems that no browser is perfect though. :-(

Answer (score 2):

So after having the same issue it appears that `border-collapse:collapse` is the issue in webkit browsers. The fix that seemed to sort it for me was to change it to `border-collapse:separate`.

Answer (score 1):

I've recently had trouble rendering table borders in Chrome. A quick fix that helped me was to define the tr as display:block.

Answer (score 0):

looked fine to me too... one option (if you want to go to the trouble) would be to wrap the table in a div with 2px padding.

Chrome 20 on iMac looked fine though.